# Anchor link goes to page not found instead of section within same page

Tags: html, anchor

I have a piece of markup where when a user clicks on "find a rider" the browser is supposed to take the user down to where the participants are on the same page. But when clicking the link it just takes me to a page not found on chrome, edge, and firefox (can't test safari).

```
<div class="container-fluid blue">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1 class="white">Prairie Women on Snowmobiles</h1>
        <a href="#find" class="btn white main-cta elevation-z12" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">Find a Rider</a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="hero elevation-z12" style="background-image: url('../images/content/pagebuilder/PWOS_banner.jpg');"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="text-center">Prairie Women on Snowmobiles</h2>
            <p>A non-profit organization whose annual missions are provincial awareness events that are designed to focus attention on breast cancer and the recreation of snowmobiling as well as raise the much-needed funds for breast cancer research. Over the past 18 years we have raised almost $2.5 million for the cause. To learn more about Prairie Women on Snowmobiles <a href="../site/SPageServer/?pagename=PWOS_SK_About">click here</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Riders</h2>
            <p>Meet our 2020 Riders</p>
        </div>
        <div class="events">
            <div class="event-display" id="find">
                [[S51:PWOS_SK_reus_riders]]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

normally to fix this I would just put the url in the link "../site/SPageServer/?pagename=PWOS_SK_homepage#find" and that works, however, doing that will break my url tracking if people land on the page using the vanity url.

Here's a link to the page:

https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/SPageServer/?pagename=PWOS_SK_homepage

any help is appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you are trying to do with an <a> tag (without keeping the URL params). Would you be willing to write a JS function that uses the `scrollTo` function to roll down to `#find`? You could even animate it so it feels like you're being brought there

Comment: @adr5240 actually that's a solid idea, the scrollTo would prevent the anchor link from having to use the full url right?

Comment: @adr5240 yes! the ScrollTo idea was perfect. I don't have to mess with any urls or anything like that and my tracking parameters stay intact! Can you please put this down as the answer.

Comment: Just checked your site and see it working, good stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it would be better to do this with simple JS instead of playing with browser functionality. Without touching the HTML and assuming you have jQuery on the site, I would add something like the following in a script tag (obviously below both the `<a href='#find'>` and `div#find`)

```
jQuery("a[href='#find']").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery("body, html").animate({ 
        scrollTop: jQuery("#find").offset().top 
    });
})
```

This allows you to stay on the page without linking away/messing up tracking data while the window will scroll to the proper element no matter how far down. Hope this helps (even though you managed it before me ;) )

Comment: thank you! the scrollTo idea was something I didn't even think of, so I googled it and it was the perfect solution to my problem. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your page starts with `<base href="https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/" />` so when you click on `href="#find"` it resolves to `https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/#find`.

You need to write your URL relative to the base URL, not the current page.

Comment: That's a good point. The problem is the url for a page is created by the CMS, so I don't think I can change it.

Answer (score -1):

When you hover the mouse over the link you see:

https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/#find

but you expect:

https://secure2.convio.net/cco/site/SPageServer/?pagename=PWOS_SK_homepage#find

This is caused by the  tag in the header.